# PHP array_count_values(); sees i and î as different letters

Tags: php, word-count

I work on some arabic style text. There is an array `$word =  array();`.

It stores some arabic words '`lim', 'ali', 'kefrâ', 'lîm'`.

You see that some word have hats on them(we call them like that). I try to count every word with method `array_count_values($word);` However it sees `lim` and `lîm` as two different words. It should count them as one. Is there a different method for it ? What can i do? Thanks.

Comment: They are different letters, but you can always use [iconv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) to convert to ISO-8859-1 using transliteration

Answer (score 0):

You can write specific function, that convert chars "with hats" in string into characters without those. There is an example (words are in Polish, but principle is exactly the same):

```
<?php

$word = array('źrebię', 'łódź', 'wiazanka', 'lodź', 'wiązanka');

$result = array_count_values($word);
var_dump($result); //its wrong answer

$wordConverted = array();
foreach($word as $element)
{
    $wordConverted[] = transformSpecialChars($element);
}

var_dump(array_count_values($wordConverted)); //count correctly


function transformSpecialChars($string)
{
    $replaceFrom = array('ą', 'ę', 'ź', 'ż', 'ł', 'ó');
    $replaceTo = array('a', 'e', 'z', 'z', 'l', 'o');

    return str_replace($replaceFrom, $replaceTo, $string);
}
```

And result of both `var_dump`s:

```
// WRONG
array(5) {
  ["źrebię"]=>
  int(1)
  ["łódź"]=>
  int(1)
  ["wiazanka"]=>
  int(1)
  ["lodź"]=>
  int(1)
  ["wiązanka"]=>
  int(1)
}

// SEEMS FINE
array(3) {
  ["zrebie"]=>
  int(1)
  ["lodz"]=>
  int(2)
  ["wiazanka"]=>
  int(2)
}
```

Of course you should suit arrays used to conversion (`$replaceFrom` and `$replaceTo`) to your needs.